# Converting JSON to CSV

Tags: java, json, rest, csv

I have a JSON of the format below and I am trying to write to CSV:

```
{
    "results": [{

            "geo_position": {
                "Field1": 11,
                "Filed2": 12
            },
            "Field3": 13,
            "Filed4": 14,
            "Field5": 15
        },

        {
            "geo_position": {
                "Field1": 21,
                "Filed2": 22
            },
            "Field3": 23,
            "Filed4": 24,
            "Filed5": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

---

I am expecting output like:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
11,12,13,14,15
21,22,23,24,25
```

---

I am getting output CSV as below:

```
    geo_position,field3,field4,field5
   {Field1:11,Field2:12}, 13,14,15
   {Field2:21,Field2:22},23,24,25
```

---

My java code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray);
System.out.println(jsonObj);
JSONArray docs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
File file=new File("C:/fromJSON2.csv");
String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
```

Can some one help me to figure out why I am getting in different format. What should I do to get in the format I expect?

Comment: all the work is being done by CDL.toString, whatever that is.

Comment: you should include more info about it.

Comment: @sandy about the CDL.toString();

Comment: Please post the method CDL.toString

Comment: i am using org.json.CDL;https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/CDL.java

Comment: If you need the solution to be done with CDL, you should say that in the title, in the description, and add a tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are some typos in the data.

You can try **[json2flat](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat)** for converting JSON docs to get an equivalent CSV representation.
If you want to try for more JSON doc click **[here](https://j2flateval.herokuapp.com/)**.

For the JSON data :

```
{
    "results": [{

            "geo_position": {
                "Field1": 11,
                "Field2": 12
            },
            "Field3": 13,
            "Field4": 14,
            "Field5": 15
        },

        {
            "geo_position": {
                "Field1": 21,
                "Field2": 22
            },
            "Field3": 23,
            "Field4": 24,
            "Field5": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

Equivalent CSV representation :

```
results/Field3,results/Field4,results/Field5,results/geo_position/Field1,results/geo_position/Field2
13.0,14.0,15.0,11.0,12.0
23.0,24.0,25.0,21.0,22.0
```

The code is also preety simple.

```
JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(jsonString);
flatMe
    .json2Sheet()
    .headerSeparator("/")
    .write2csv("test.csv");
```

This will write the result to test.csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray);
    JSONArray docs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
    File file = new File("C:/fromJSON2.csv");
    String csv = getDocs(docs);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
  }

  public static String getDocs(JSONArray ja) throws JSONException {
    String result = "";
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jo = ja.optJSONObject(i);
      if (jo != null) {
        getAllTopKeyAndValue(jo, map);
        if (i == 0) {
          result += keyOfMap2String(map) + "\n";
        }
        result += valueOfMap2String(map) + "\n";
      }
    }
    return result;
  }


  public static void getAllTopKeyAndValue(JSONObject jo, Map<String, Integer> map) {
    if (jo != null) {
      JSONArray names = jo.names();
      String string = "";
      List integers = new ArrayList<>();
      if (names != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
          String name = names.getString(i);
          JSONObject object = jo.optJSONObject(name);
          if (object != null) {
            getAllTopKeyAndValue(object, map);
          } else {
            map.put(name, (Integer) jo.get(name));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static String keyOfMap2String(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    String result = "";
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
      result += entry.getKey();
      if (iter.hasNext()) {
        result += ",";
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static String valueOfMap2String(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    String result = "";
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
      result += entry.getValue();
      if (iter.hasNext()) {
        result += ",";
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your JSON structure is

```
{
"results":
[
    {
        "geo_position": {"Field1":11,"Filed2":12},
        "Field3":13,
        "Filed4":14,
        "Field5":15
    },

    {
        "geo_position":{"Field1":21,"Filed2":22},
        "Field3":23,
        "Filed4":24,
        "Filed5":25
    }

]
}
```

For it to work about the way you want it to work, it should be something like:

```
{
"results":
[
    {
        "Field1":11,
        "Filed2":12,
        "Field3":13,
        "Filed4":14,
        "Field5":15
    },

    {
        "Field1":21,
        "Filed2":22,
        "Field3":23,
        "Filed4":24,
        "Filed5":25
    }

]
}
```

what you could do something like

```
for(int i = 0; i<resultsJSONArray.length(); ++i){ 
    if(resultsJSONArray.get(i).has("geo_position")) {
          String names[] = JSONObject.getNames(resultsJSONArray.get(i).get("geo_position")));
          for(int i = 0; i<names().length; ++i) {                                       
              resultsJSONArray.get(i).put(names[i],resultsJSONArray.get(i).get("geo_position").get(names[i]));
          }
          JSONObject.getNames(resultsJSONArray.get(i).remove("geo_position"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that how to process it shld i convert before?

Comment: yup. you should manipulate the json objects with the methods from http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: edited my answer with something that should be about right. didn't check it though.